# How to request desktop sites from a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, mobile-browser

I'm developing a web application using `ReactJS` that fetches the data from various websites using `axios` and `cheerio`. This application works completely fine in desktop browsers, but when i use the same application in mobile browser, the data is not fetched correctly as the class names in the mobile version of the sites that i'm requesting are completely different.

How can i request desktop sites from the mobile browser using `axios` or any other method that i can use in `ReactJS`?

Comment: I think you best bet is to craft a `User-Agent` header that can potentially request the desktop version.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to set a `User-Agent` for `axios` to request only desktop page even in the mobile browser.

Comment: For example if you want to add a header for all requests you can do something like this: `axios.defaults.headers.common['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0`